What is the difference between the virial radius, the total mass-energy density radius and the critical density radius for a galaxy?
For a regular spiral galaxy like the Milky Way, how are these concepts different from each other?

It might help to link where you saw the terms. I work in astrophysics and have not seen the latter two used as standard terms.

It was actually from another StackExchange question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406867/intuitive-understanding-of-the-virial-radius-mass
